# Building both war and ear files for same project using maven

Tags: java, maven-2, ejb, maven-plugin

In my project i have both web related stuff(jsps, controllers, ..) and EJB beans.
Now i need to build war file with web related stuff and deploy that into tomcat and
need to build ear file for EJB's and deploy that into jboss using maven.

Can anyone suggest me a solution to modify the pom.xml accordingly.

Thank you,
Pavan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to split your project into multiple sub-projects: one builds the EJBs, one builds the WAR, and a third packages them together. This is described in [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-relationships.html), and with an example in [Better Builds with Maven](http://www.maestrodev.com/better-builds-with-maven/4-building-j2ee-applications/organizing-the-daytrader-directory-structure).

Comment: No, we cannt split the source into sub-projects.

Comment: @Pawan - then don't use Maven. And I'm serious about that: Maven makes your life very difficult if you don't want to use it the way its developers intended. You will probably be happier with Ant, using the Maven Ant Tasks to retrieve dependencies.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on using both Maven and Ant tasks in this case?

Comment: @Pawan - it's all in the docs: http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reference link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use profiles. In each profile in your pom.xml you may specify any configuration you like. That configuration will be applied when you run mvn -PyourProfileName.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  
But if we use profiles we need to run mvn command more than once. So, is there something else we can?

Answer (score 0):

You can fit it all in one pom.xml:

As a start, make/use your stadard "war" pom.xml.

Create the folder "src/main/application/META-INF".

Put the ear relevant files like "application.xml" (mandatory), "jboss-app.xml" and/or "jboss-deployment-structure.xml" in there.

Expand your pom.xml:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/application</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>META-INF/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

and further:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <ear
                            destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.ear"
                            appxml="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/application.xml">
                            <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}"
                                includes="META-INF/*.xml" excludes="META-INF/application.xml" />
                            <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}"
                                includes="${project.build.finalName}.war" />
                        </ear>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

hint: application.xml should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="6">
  <display-name>XXX.ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>XXX.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>XXX</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```